# Are there any references that the English language is written and read from left to right and from top to bottom?

Tags: british-english, writing, reading

What is the basis this?
I have practically done hours of research and I couldn't find any source or reference about this.

I AM NOT ASKING WHY. I AM ASKING FOR A REFERENCE.

Comment: I'm baffled by this question. Why would you need a reference for this?

Comment: ?si ti kniht uoy od yhW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet you will find:

> Direction Left-to-right

Here it describes how you could cite the page: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:CiteThisPage&page=English_alphabet&id=883793073

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find one for a "**reference**" to your question concerning reading/writing direction of English. The English language has evolved over time from the many other languages that originally preceded it. You may or may not find references for one of the several "ancestral" languages, but that would be another question. I offer you the "**History of English**" Wikipedia page with it's references below.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_English